# difference between !duplicated() and unique()

Tags: r

I can't figure out what is the difference between these two functions in R.
I have a data.frame, and I want to remove rows corresponding to duplicated values in a given column;

```
    Acc         Probe             Coord_homol
1   NR_004442.1 225541_at~122     391
2   NM_028059.2 241348_at~444     4642
3   NM_028059.2 241348_at~468     4666
4   NM_001114   212306_at~4357    5034
5   NM_010573.2 230472_at~402     1987
6   NM_029633.2 212306_at~4357    4289
7   NM_00108196 212306_at~4357    4292
8   NM_029891.2 205004_at~3421    2963
9   NM_029891.2 205004_at~3635    3173
10  NM_007892.2 221586_s_at~1356 1257
11  NR_036613.1 208672_s_at~829  1301
12  NR_036613.1 208673_s_at~1472 1854
13  NM_011078.3 212726_at~3872    5175
14  NM_011078.3 212726_at~3887    5190
15  NM_013915.3 207164_s_at~1523 2911
```

in this case, I would like to remove rows 7 because the probe is the same as in row 6 (rows with same probes do not have to be successive ones).

I first tried unique(), and later found duplicated.
but if the following command

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$probe),]

dat[unique(dat$probe),]
```

give the same number of lines in the resulting data.frame, the results are not the same.

I tried on a much simpler case, like the following:

a simple data.frame:

```
> dat
   probe val
1    aaa  10
2    bbb  12
3    ccc  45
4    ddd  32
5    aaa  42
6    eee  10
7    fff  13
8    ccc  85
9    aaa  75
10   ddd  64
```

using !duplicated(): it seems to be what I want to do;

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$probe),]

  probe val
1   aaa  10
2   bbb  12
3   ccc  45
4   ddd  32
6   eee  10
7   fff  13
```

using unique():

```
dat[unique(dat$probe),]
```

I get:

```
 probe val
1   aaa  10
2   bbb  12
3   ccc  45
4   ddd  32
5   aaa  42
6   eee  10
```

Not what I want;

But what exactly unique() is doing ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Run `!duplicated(dat$probe)` and `unique(dat$probe)`; you'll see that one gives a vector of T/F values and the other a list of the unique values.

Comment: I think your conceptual problem would be solved by looking at unique(dat$prob) vs. !duplicated(dat$prob). I think the first sentence on each of the help pages for ?duplicated and ?unique would be an instructive read.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: Thanks; if I understand well; unique is returning only probes that are unique and discard all occurence of probes that are multiple, whereas duplicated help me remove duplicates. Am I right ?

Then why is it not the case in the simple example; and why both functions give the same number of lines in the resulting data.frame ?

Comment: Suppose instead your `$probe` column contained numbers.  Consider:  `mydata$probe <- c(1,2,3,2,5,4,7,5,6) ;foo<- unique(mydata$probe)` . If you take the result, i.e. `c(1,2,3,5,4,7,6)` and extract `mydata[c(foo),]` , what will you get?

Comment: This is the general relationship between both functions: `x[!duplicated(x)] == unique(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique` is returning a factor and the numeric levels of the factor are being used for indexing rather than the labels.

```
uni <- unique(dat$probe)
str(uni)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "aaa","bbb","ccc",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

It is like you are doing this:

```
nums <- as.numeric(unique(dat$probe))
dat[nums,]
  probe val
1   aaa  10
2   bbb  12
3   ccc  45
4   ddd  32
5   aaa  42
6   eee  10
```

`unique` is returning a factor because we are putting a factor into it in this case. It doesn't always return factors. For example, `unique(as.character(dat$probe))` would return characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot; now I understand my mistake; the factor are those that are expected, but the numeric value associated with these factor acting as an index return me the first 6 elements of the data.frame, not the unique elements.
duplicated is definitely what I should use.
A last question, if it is not too much; how unique should be used and for what purpose; the help page is a little bit too much technical for my level of comprehension of R (although it is improving).

Comment: unique() has many uses.  A simple use case is identifying typos and errors.  Another use case would be to see which days measured events occurred on in an irregular time series.